# How to SUM column in MySQL left join

Tags: mysql

So i have table **cont_selling**

```
---------------------------------
cont_selling_id   |     date    | 
---------------------------------
     1            | 2015-05-24  | 
     2            | 2015-06-06  | 
---------------------------------
```

table 02 **cont_sold**

```
   ----------------------------------------------------
    cont_sold_id |    cont_selling_id   |     price   | 
    ---------------------------------------------------
      1          |         1            |       10    | 
      2          |         1            |       10    | 
      3          |         1            |       30    | 
      4          |         2            |       20    | 
      5          |         2            |       10    | 
    --------------------------------------------------
```

and table 03 **payment**

```
 ----------------------------------------------
payment_id   |  cont_selling_id |      paid   | 
-----------------------------------------------
    1        |         1        |       10    | 
    2        |         2        |       10    | 
    3        |         1        |       20    | 
    4        |         1        |       10    | 
    5        |         2        |       10    | 
-----------------------------------------------
```

now i need to SELECT table based on

now i want to merge all these three tables based on **cont_selling** table **cont_selling_id** column

and want to SUM cont_sold table price column and payment table paid column

this is what i want to do

expecting output

```
---------------------------------------------
cont_selling_id  |    price    |      paid   | 
---------------------------------------------
       1         |      50     |       40    | 
       2         |      30     |       20    | 
---------------------------------------------
```

so i tried like this in mysql query but it give wrong sum result

```
                    SELECT 

                    SUM(Z.price) as total, 
                    SUM(P.amount) as paid

                    FROM cont_selling S

                    LEFT JOIN cont_sold Z
                    ON S.cont_selling_id = Z.cont_selling_id

                    LEFT JOIN payment P
                    ON S.cont_selling_id = P.cont_selling_id    

                    GROUP BY S.cont_selling_id
```

for this above query i m getting output like this

```
---------------------------------------------
cont_selling_id  |    price    |      paid   | 
---------------------------------------------
       1         |      150    |       40    | 
       2         |      60     |      120    | 
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you show the result you get?

Comment: @Jens i have added my output with this question. kindly check it, Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how you can do it using the aggegare part into inner queries and then join

```
select 
cs.cont_selling_id,
price,
paid
from cont_selling cs
left join(
 select sum(price) as price , cont_selling_id from cont_sold
 group by cont_selling_id
)x on x.cont_selling_id = cs.cont_selling_id,
left join(
 select sum(paid) as paid , cont_selling_id from payment
 group by cont_selling_id
)y
on y.cont_selling_id = cs.cont_selling_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make two different queries with `SUM` and then combine them to get the desired result:

```
SELECT T1.cont_selling_id,T1.price,T2.paid
FROM
(SELECT c.cont_selling_id,SUM(cs.price) as price
 FROM cont_selling c LEFT JOIN
     cont_sold cs ON c.cont_selling_id=cs.cont_selling_id
 GROUP BY c.cont_selling_id) as T1 JOIN
(SELECT c.cont_selling_id,SUM(p.paid) as paid
 FROM cont_selling c LEFT JOIN
      payment p ON p.cont_selling_id=c.cont_selling_id
  GROUP BY c.cont_selling_id) as T2 ON T1.cont_selling_id=T2.cont_selling_id
```

Result:

```
cont_selling_id price   paid
----------------------------
1               50      40
2               30      20
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fe67/9).

Answer (score 1):

This untested query should work:

```
with a as(select  cont_selling_id  , sum(price) as totalprice from cont_sold group by cont_selling_id),
with a as(select  cont_selling_id  , sum(paid) as totalpaid from payment group by cont_selling_id),
select c.cont_selling_id , totalprice, totalpaid from cont_selling c left join a.count_selling_id = c.count_selling_id
left join b.count_selling_id = c.count_selling_id
```

You have to create temporary tables, because there is no dependency between your table for price and paid.